# Using Audience targeting with View web parts

Tags: sharepoint-online, content, audience-targeting

I have managed to create an Audience target and assign this audience target to a specific view web part. This works perfectly, i.e. I am not supposed to see the content of the view and when I click on the view, the page is empty for me. However, I want now, to be able to not even see the view and therefore not be able to click on it and see it as empty. The reason is that I will have a lot of these views assigned to other Audience targets, and the whole document library will get too messy with Views that in reality only correspond to small specific sets of people and not everyone.

What can be done about this?